# Run 2 update transactions for same row

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

Given 2 simple procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE simpleproc()
BEGIN 
    UPDATE mytable SET name = 'bbb' WHERE id = 1;
    DO SLEEP(15);
END 
$$ DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE simpleproc2()
BEGIN 
     UPDATE mytable SET name = 'jjj' WHERE id = 1;
END 
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Then in one connection (in mysql workbench) I run first procedure:

```
call simpleproc();
```

and in second connection, run second procedure

```
call simpleproc2();
```

What surprised me, is that second transaction no waits for first and executes immediately.

What I missed? why first transaction no locks row `id=1`?

Table `mytable` have `InnoDB` engine

Comment: Why will it lock, unless you use an explicit `LOCK TABLES mytable WRITE;`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - But this will lock entire table, there is no `row level locking` by default in mysql? (I mean `delete` and `update` operations)

Comment: row level locking will initiate only when update statement is triggered

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya -  Then why second transaction not waits for first? `DO SLEEP(15)` not "holds" transaction for a while?

Comment: Do Sleep does not specify which table to lock. It is a plain simple sleep process which lets the thread hang. Why would MySQL lock a table or a specific row in sleep.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - I thought `Do Sleep()`  could "hold" row locked,  because it is together with `update`, within same transaction

Comment: Make sure you have started a transaction. After your edit (placing the sleep after the update), and if you started a transaction, and if the row exists, the row should be locked and the second update should wait.

Comment: @Solarflare - Thank you man, I missed that `begin..end` not means transaction start and end by default in mysql, I added `start transaction..commit` and works as expected, thanks

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Thank you also for your help